# Display image on applet

Tags: java, image, swing, applet, jtree

I am using `Jtree` for listing various images of a directory,  I want to display image on `applet` when the user click on the image name displayed in the Tree, the code i'm using is as below, `ta` is an object of the applet because i'm using it in another class.

```
private void displayImage(URL furl, String fname) {


    ta.Picture = ta.getImage(furl, fname);
    prepareImage(ta.Picture, this);
    Graphics g = ta.imageCanvas.getGraphics();
    g.clearRect(10, 10, 800, 800);
    g.drawImage(ta.Picture, 10, 10, this);

} // displayImage

public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FileTreeNode node = (FileTreeNode) tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
    System.out.println("slecte asldf " + node.isLeaf());
    if (node.isLeaf()) 
    {

        currentFile = node.file;
        System.out.println("File name " + currentFile.getName());
        try 
        {
            URL furl = new URL("file:/F:/photos");
            displayImage(furl, currentFile.getName());
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException mle) 
        {
            System.out.println("Exception::::::" + mle);
        }

    } 
    else
        currentFile = null;

}
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are showing files from the local filesystem, working with URLs is not required. Use

```
displayImage(currentFile);
```

and rewrite that method as following:

```
private void displayImage(File file) {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
    ta.image = image;
    ta.repaint();
 }
```

where the paint method of the (I an assuming) component ta must be like

```
BufferedImage image;
public void paint(Graphics g) { 
    g.clearRect(10, 10, 800, 800);
    g.drawImage(ta.Picture, 10, 10, this);
}
```

Because of security reasons, the applet will only be able to access the file system if signed or running without security manager (most often on the same computer).

Comment: *Because of security reasons, the applet will only be able to access the file system if signed or running on the same computer.* +1. Not too sure though about the `paint` I prefer `JPanel` and `paintComponent`

Comment: Surely, if this is a Swing applet. I was not sure, maybe an AWT applet.

Comment: *"the applet will only be able to access the file system if signed or running on the same computer."*  No.  the last part of that should be *"if signed or.."* ..operating with no security manager.  A sand-boxed applet cannot access the local file system at all, same/different computer makes no difference.

Comment: Agree. It used to be a common problem that somebody tests applet in IDE where is has more access (normally runs without security manager) and then it does not work over Internet. Just wanted to warn. Maybe more recent applet development tools install that manager automatically. Updated the post

Answer (score 2):

> But its not working.

This is in no way helpful, do you get exceptions? What happens? Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help sooner

> I want to display image on applet when the user click on the image
>   name displayed in the Tree, the code i'm using is as below, ta is an
>   object of the applet because i'm using it in another class.

IMO you are going about it wrong using the `JPanel` object and `Component#getGraphics`.

- Dont use `Component#getGraphics()` as its not good practice and not persistent thus on next call to `repaint()` the screen will be cleared.
- Dont use Applet with Swing components rather use `JApplet`.

Add a custom `JPanel` with *getters and setters* for `BufferedImage` variable to the container and than override `paintComponnet` and draw the `BufferedImage` there.

Now to change the `BufferedImage` simply call the *setter* i.e `setBackgroundImage(BufferedImage img)` and than call `repaint()` on `JPanel` to show the changes. Like so:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage bg;

    public MyPanel(BufferedImage bi) {
        bg=bi;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);

       Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;
       g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
       g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));

       g2d.drawImage(bg,0,0,this);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(bg.getWidth(),bg.getHeight());
    }

    public BufferedImage setBackgroundImage(BufferedImage bi) {
        bg=bi;
    }
}
```

Now we use it like so:

```
MyPanel mp=new MyPanel(...);//create the panel with an image
...
add(mp);//add to container
...
mp.setBackgroundImage(..);//change the image being displayed

mp.repaint();//so the new image may be painted
```

Comment: _Don't use Applet with Swing components rather use JApplet._ Can you explain me why ? Just curious to know.

Comment: @Che Applet is AWT...JApplet is Swing

Comment: But Swing is built on AWT so what will be the problem if I use? Is it bcoz one is dependent on the OS and one is not so it may cause any look and feel issue?

Comment: Just because it was the foundation and no syntax errors occur doesnt mean we can mix the 2 without problems. Its like using an AWT `KeyListener` for Swing components there is focus issues... unusual things can occur. Thus its not recommended to use. and yes and Im sure L&F issues could occur too...

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes I just cast to Graphics2D in order to prompt OP to use it and `RenderingHint`s (which I have now added). As for `this` why should it be used? I never used it before in the context of `JPanel` painting an image which has already been loaded/nothing implements an `Observable`?

Comment: Re. `this` my statement makes a lot more sense if the panel declares `public MyPanel(Image bi) {`  rather than `public MyPanel(BufferedImage bi) {` as it does.  I don't think there are any ways to load a `BufferedImage` asynchronously.  OTOH, `this` is as short to type as `null` ..so why *ever* use `null` for the `ImageObserver` of a component that is one?

Comment: *so why ever use null for the ImageObserver of a component that is one?* agreed +1 and edited code to reflect changes.